# Sequelize model.init() call overwrites previous model instance of different db connection

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using multiple database connections with the same model which I am saving inside of a Map on startup of the application. The issue I had is that an initialized model for db connection `conn1` has been overwritten by subsequent `ExampleModel.init();` calls with db connection `conn2`.

#### Model

```
import { Model } from 'sequelize';

export class ExampleModel extends Model {
    static init(sequelize, options) {
        return super.init(
            {...}, 
            {
                sequelize, // This connection instance is being overwritten by subsequent calls
                ...
            }
        );
    }
}
```

#### Initialization

```
for (const tenant of tenants) {
   modelMap.set(tenant, new Map());
   const tenantDB = new Sequelize(...);
   
   ExampleModel.init(tenantDB, {}),
   modelMap.get(tenant).set('ExampleModel', ExampleModel');
}
```

#### Problem description

1. Init database connection for tenant1, `conn1`
2. Add model ExampleModel to `conn1`

```
// Returns connection to db1, which is correct
modelMap.get(<tenant1>).get('ExampleModel').options.sequelize.connectionManager.config.database
-> conn1
```

3. Init database connection for tenant2, `conn2`
4. Add model ExampleModel to `conn2`

```
// Returns connection to db2, which is wrong
modelMap.get(<tenant1>).get('ExampleModel').options.sequelize.connectionManager.config.database
-> conn2 // Connection has been overwritten
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following solution:

#### Model

```
export const createExampleModel = (sequelizeInstance) => {
    const ExampleModel = sequelizeInstance.define(
        'ExampleModel',
         {...},
         {...}
    );
    return ExampleModel;
}
```

#### Initialization

```
for (const tenant of tenants) {
    const tenantDB = new Sequelize(...);

    const ExampleModel = createExampleModel(tenantDB);
}
```

#### Accessing the model

```
tenantDB.models.ExampleModel
```

Now every model has the correct database connection associated.